# AjaxForm file upload in Firefox 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, jquery

```
<form action="upload.aspx" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ajaxUploadForm" method="post">
<input type="file" name="fileBase" id="fileBase"><input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>

$( "#ajaxUploadForm" ).ajaxForm( {
iframe: "true",cache: false,
success: function ( response )
{
   var msg = $.parseJSON( $( response ).val() );
   alert ( msg.status); 
}
}} );
```

When i try to send ajax form i have an error (only in Firefox 4):

"uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x805e0006 [nsIDOMHTMLFormElement.submit]"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 ()"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/Scripts/jquery/jquery.form.js :: doSubmit :: line 295"  data: no]
Line 0"

i use jquery 1.5.1 and jquery.from 2.67

Thx for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There is a new [version](https://github.com/malsup/form) of the JQuery Form plug in that was released 2 days ago. I tried their [demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) in Firefox 4 and it seems to work very well, so maybe you can try changing the plug in version.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I encountered similar error when trying to send ajax request with jquery. It worked on chrome, IE, Opera, but failed on FF. After hours wasted on debugging it turned out that AdBlock Plus was blocking my request. So if You didn't solve the problem already, try to turn off AdBlock.

Answer (score -2):

You can't upload files using ajax, for that you either need to use an iframe or flash.

Comment: Jquery.form plugin have option "iframe: 'true'", and it appened the iframe. This code works perfect except Firefox 4

Comment: Are you posting to the same domain the page originated from?